# Terraform NULL resource not getting executed every time inside a Terraform module

Tags: module, terraform, null, resources

I am running a terraform NULL resource. This NULL resource is present in a file (main.tf) and this file is being executed by the terraform module.

Like this:

```
module "module_name" {
  source = "location of **main.tf**"
  param1 = "value1"
  param2 = "value2"
}
```

Above is just an example of how my code structure is.

So, when I execute this terraform module, it doesn't recreate the null resource every time, BUT when I go to main.tf file directory and run terraform commands, it recreates the null resource every time.

So, null resource gets executed every time when I run the terraform commands on main.tf but it doesn't gets executed when I run the same terraform commands from the terraform module.

PLEASE DO NOTE that I am using triggers section in my null resource.

```
resource "null_resource" "xyz" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo HELLO WORLD!!"
  }
}
```

I tried to execute the null resource every time using triggers.
My expectation is that the null resource gets executed every time
Actual result is null resource not getting executed every time when using terraform modules

Comment: Does the null resource depend on another resource from the module? Or it is just a command that needs to run?

Comment: Null resource is simply running a command.

Answer (score 0):

I caught the mistake.
The reason why null resource was not getting executed is because null resource is kept inside a terraform module i.e in the backend code which gets called by the terraform root module.

To test that, I created a sample.tf file with the null resource in it, and ran the terraform init, plan and apply commands. and the null resource was getting executed every time ( with the timestamp trigger placed obviously ). This is the expected behavior.

So, conclusion derived is, null resource must be kept in a *.tf file and terraform commands must be executed on that *.tf file.

I am not sure, why the same behavior can't be achieved when using Terraform modules. But I hope in future, terraform adds this functionality in future releases.

Thank You !!!